# "Release" a process from my Panel (MainWindowHandle)

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, process

I run this code to set the parent window of a process:

```
SetParent(masterP.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

When I close my application I want to change the MainWindowHandle of the masterP process to the operatingsystem. In other words, I want to "release" it back to it's normal "state".

So basicly my question is, what code do I need to use to be able to do this? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Key phrase: *"It’s one of those “if you don’t already know what the consequences are, then you are not smart enough to do it correctly” things. You must first become the master of the rules before you can start breaking them."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using winforms and WinApi:

```
SetParent(masterP.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Thank you! I read something about setting the second argument to null but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Mainwindowhandle appears as '0' due to window tearing when using SetParent. Before using the SetParent operation, you need to use the following code:

```
private IntPtr backupMainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
     backupMainWindowHandle = notepad.MainWindowHandle;
     SetParent(notepad.MainWindowHandle, SetToHandle); //Dock
}
```

Below is the code to release:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetParent(backupMainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero); //Undock
}
```